# PHP and AJAX to get a variable back

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic

I'm using PHP and AJAX to make a post in the page. Request.php requests the second return.php. But I dont get the return:

request.php

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">  
   function getnumber(){  
    var number=document.getElementById("number").value;  
    alert(number);  
    }

    function post(){
     var numberp=document.getElementById("number").value;  
     $.post('return.php',{postnumber:numberp}, 
     function(data){ 
     var result = $('#numberp').html(data); 
     return result; });
    }
</script>

<form>
    Enter No:<input type="text" id="number" name="number"/><br/>  
    <input type="button" value="Get number" onclick="getnumber()"/>  
</form> 

<form>
    Enter No:<input type="text" id="number" name="number"/><br/>  
    <input type="button" value="Get number processed" onclick="post()"/>  
</form>
```

return.php

```
<?php
function returnString() {
$post_number = $_POST['postnumber'];
echo "the name entered ->", $post_number, " <- hier";
}
returnString();
?>
```

Expected result is the number is returned by return.php

Comment: Have you checked your browser console to see if your `jQuery` post is being executed as you expect or maybe checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: yes thats the odd, it doesnt show any.

Comment: any reason your js and forms html is in a php file?

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic what problem do you see with having the `javascript` on the same page for the `php`? It isn't how I would structure things but I also don't see how this would cause any problems relevant to your comment...

Comment: no problem, I am just curious for purposes of testing.

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic because there are also some php calls in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is id should be unique.you are using one `id= number` in two places which creates ambiguity.Check this working code.

request.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getnumber(){
    var number1=document.getElementById("number1").value;
    alert(number1);
    }


    function post(){
     var number2=document.getElementById("number2").value;
     $.post('return.php',{postnumber:number2},
     function(data){
     var result = $('#numberp').html(data);
     console
     return result; });
    }
</script>

<form>A
    Enter No:<input type="text" id="number1" name="number1"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Get number" onclick="getnumber()"/>
</form>

<form>
    Enter No:<input type="text" id="number2" name="number2"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Get number processed" onclick="post()"/>
</form>
<div id="numberp"></div>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

return.php

```
<?php

function returnString() {
    $post_number = $_POST['postnumber'];
    echo "the name entered ->", $post_number, " <- hier";
}
returnString();
?>
```

Comment: those input fields are in separate forms, it is ok to do that as long as he selects the the right form when he is handling the submission - but otherwise, yeah, in a real environment, you probably want to be more precise.

Comment: Yeah this is in the separate forms,but eventually you are getting the value through id.So it definitely creates ambiguity

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the name attribute, didn't notice the id's were also named number.  You are 100% correct.  Id's should always be unique.

Comment: @CodeBreaker as I commented Gaurav's suggestions just by changing the id's wont work. I have tried that before. Just on little detail you mentioed is to add the <div id="number2"></div> without this it wont work. Thank you!   I dont get why though? Why we need the <div> here and why just for the second (ajax) element?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to use `sumbit()` to capture the form data.  This way, we can serialize the data and send it to your form processor (note that `serialize()` will serialize all the input fields in your form, it would then be up to your form handler to pull the right values.

In return.php i have modified your `$_POST` variable to reflect the input field `name` attribute value.  The `name` attributes is how php knows to look for form values (that I know).  Lastly, i changed your input type to `submit` and inside the `submit()` handler I am using `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default behavior and use AJAX.

It is more semantically correct to use `type="submit"` for submit buttons.

Also, there is no need to use the `onclick=""` attribute in your form element, it is a bit cleaner to separate your JS from your HTML and handle the submit.

The following code works on my machines.

request.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<form >
    Enter No:<input type="text" id="number" name="number"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Get number" onclick="getnumber()"/>
</form>

<form id="postForm">
    Enter No:<input type="text" id="number" name="number"/><br/>
    <input  type="submit" value="Get number processed" />
</form>

<div id="numberp"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getnumber(){
        var number=document.getElementById("number").value;
        alert(number);
    }

    $('#postForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        // $(this) refers to the form in this context
        var data = $(this).serialize()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './return.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(res) {
                $('#numberp').html(res);
            }
        });
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

return.php

```
<?php
function returnString() {
$post_number = $_POST['number'];
echo "the name entered ->", $post_number, " <- hier";
}
returnString();
```

Comment: this works like a charm, and it is indeed more clear and readable. thank you! I just dont get why the form <id> wont suffice and we need the <div id>

Comment: The only div you need is the output div, which was in your code.  You were targeting #numberp in your success function so that needs to exist somewhere on your document.  It doesn’t have to be an Id or a div, but your example was targeting it

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant. In my original code (see above) I return "numberp" in my post() but I do not explicit it in my request form. I forgot the output <div>  and that was the trick. Anyway your solution serializing the whole form is also a good solution. I appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `post` request might be failing. Add an `error` callback to report on that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'return.php',
    data: {postnuber: numberp},
    success: function(res) {
        $('#numberp').html(res);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('error: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right .only mistake in form elements. you write "number" id two times.so program can't get the value. Just replace the id like below.

In The first form change the id

```
<form>
    Enter No:<input type="text" id="getnumber" name="number"/><br/>  
    <input type="button" value="Get number" onclick="getnumber()"/>  
</form>
```

Comment: Yes I thought of that before posting. It doesnt work. I am suspecting its the browser

Comment: I tried your code .just replace the id in the first form . It will solve your problem

Comment: In the end the problem was the missing <div id>. See @Codebreaker s post